# Restricting ElasticBeanstalk app using security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

How to restrict elastic beanstalk web app using security groups? I tried allowing HTTP/HTTPS inbound rules to my IP address plus the eb load balancers but I get a 504 gateway time out error.

I get the IP address by looking up the network interface associated with the particular eb load balancer under EC2 > Network & Security > Network Interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding load balancer security group to EB instance and then adding my IP to load balancer security group.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses of the load balancer are subject to change. You have to allow inbound connections from the security group ID of the load balancer, not its IP address.

Comment: This does not directly answer my question but it helps, I realized I needed to allow HTTP access on load balancer security group instead of EB security group. Thanks!